# Custom URL for open graph object

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to redirect the user to a specific URL when he clicks on the title of my object.

So I tried to do this :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/myPage" />
```

Instead of this :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo strip_tags(curPageURL());?>" />
```

But Facebook can't get the meta data because it seems to use this URL.

Is there a way to redirect to any other URL? I can't add meta data on the specific page because it is not mine.

Comment: Redirect via JavaScript; or redirect via HTTP, _after_ checking if the requesting client is not the Facebook scraper.